# How to reduce size of my adHoc build

Tags: iphone, filesize

I am using too many images and music in my app..

The music is short in duration but very large in size ..
That sound is in `.caf` format

i have many sounds like this

That is why the adhoc build size reached to 35mb.And still i have to add more.

I am using that in creating system sound...

Like

```
    NSURL *tapSound   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"sound1"
                                            withExtension: @"aif"];

self.soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [tapSound retain];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (

                                      soundFileURLRef,
                                      &soundFileObject
                                      );
```

I have tried to use an mp3 or wav sound here but that is not working.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kumar Sonu:

Try compressing your sound files and compress your images if possible.

**Note**: Compressing your audio files may deteriorate your sound quality and may decrease your kbps

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes i agree to you but ....i have appx 150+ sound files and i have still 100 more to add.....if i go with you and compress them even ten my build size will be more that 25 mb......do you think this is not very large...?

Comment: @Kumar sonu: Yes it is but then I dont think the size would decrease unless you remove some of your music files.

Comment: @kumar sonu: One more thing try and use jpgs in place of png images where transperancy is not an issue. Also try using mp3 files and render them into wav or some other format of your choice when the app runs the first time and save them in your app's document directory. :)

Comment: @Kumar sonu: Did this help you?